# How can I make articles from an external data source searchable in Salesforce Knowledge?

Tags: knowledge, lightning-connect

**I think I need to use Lightning Connect, but I'm not exactly sure how to go about this.**

Answer (score 1):

Your org has to enable Lightning Connect. There's a fee for it. It's not free. To learn more about how to use it, I recommend you go through the [Lightning Connect Trailhead Module](https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/module/lightning_connect).